# Emacs transparent background on gnome-shell?

Tags: emacs, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm using emacs gui on gnome-shell(3.2). I just set transparent background as the [guide](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TransparentEmacs#toc1) shows. It actually works on xfce4 (with compositor turned on). But failed on my gnome-shell laptop.

So is there any workaround on gnome-shell to support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Shell (Gnome3) uses the Mutter window manager. There is a [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565975) about "No opacity in emacs with mutter". Possibly the bug reporter means transparency, not opacity, because this text appears in the bug report: "No transparency at all with mutter."